# projection of $x^2+y^2+z^2-yz=1$ to xoy plane

Tags: geometry, projection

if the surface is projected to yoz plane, I known than the equation of the projection is $y^2+z^2-yz-1=0$. But what what about xoy plane,  is the equation of project projection  $x^2+y^2=1$?

Comment: The unit circle $x²+y²=1$ is the intersection of the given surface with the plane $z=0$. This is not a projection, the projection you are looking for i guess is $\pi(f(x))$ where $\pi(x,y,z)=(x,y)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
x^2+y^2+z^2-yz=1
\\
z^2-yz+\left( x^2+y^2-1 \right) =0
\\
\Delta =-4x^2-3y^2+4\ge 0
\\
x^2+\frac{3}{4}y^2\le 1
$$

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

The intersection of the plane $x^2+y^2+z^2-yz=1$ with the three coordinate planes gives you the following lines:

1. in the $xy$-plane, therefore, $z=0$: $x^{2}+y^{2}=1$,
2. in the $xz$-plane, therefore, $y=0$: $x^{2}+z^{2}=1$,
3. in the $yz$-plane, therefore, $x=0$: $y^{2}+z^{2}-yz=1$.

Comment: But I think Intersecting lines do not necessarily equal projections?